# Accessing properties/methods with self in class

Tags: ios, swift, self

I was browsing Firefox's open source iOS app and discovered that they sometimes access properties in a class with `self` and some without.

My guess would have been that it's a style choice and that using explicit `self` makes it clear that it's a class property and not a local variable. But that can't be the case as both approaches (w/ and w/o `self`) are used...

The relevant code, which is troubling me, is in [AppDelegate.swift](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/blob/c296f2b3c1c7afd79569c36d57a1507e90bb29a4/Client/Application/AppDelegate.swift) from line [130](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/blob/c296f2b3c1c7afd79569c36d57a1507e90bb29a4/Client/Application/AppDelegate.swift#L130) till [136](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/blob/c296f2b3c1c7afd79569c36d57a1507e90bb29a4/Client/Application/AppDelegate.swift#L136). There the property `tabManager` is assigned with `self` and `browserViewController` without, although both are part of the same class.

```
self.tabManager = TabManager(prefs: profile.prefs, imageStore: imageStore)
self.tabManager.stateDelegate = self

//[...]

browserViewController = BrowserViewController(profile: self.profile!, tabManager: self.tabManager)
browserViewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

As I'm quite new to iOS and Swift programming, I would appreciate if someone could clarify if this was an style choice or something else :)

Answer (score 2):

> My guess would have been that it's a style choice and that using explicit self makes it clear that it's a class property and not a local variable.

Correct. `self` is the implicit message recipient if no message recipient is specified, so it amounts to the same thing. `self.tabManager` and `tabManager` are synonyms in this context (i.e. where there is no local variable `tabManager` but there is an instance property `tabManager`).

> But that can't be the case as both approaches (w/ and w/o self) are used...

That's called "carelessness" (or maybe "inconsistency"). There's no penalty for not using `self` in this situation, so this programmer sometimes doesn't do it.

As I say [in my book](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_self), I never omit `self` except by mistake. But mistakes do happen. Even I do make them.

Comment: Btw do you maybe know if there is a convention (or something) to use `self` with inherited class properties? Because that's how every open-sourced iOS app or tutorial, which I have seen, does it, but I have never seen a style-guide which recommends that...

Comment: I believe I just recommended it.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't notice the link. And thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't worry mate, I just didn't want to drag on the discussion because it wasn't going anywhere. And I never even planned to use `self` in every situation because I think it pollutes code...